# jQuery selector for element, ID, and style

Tags: jquery

It looks jquery selector for element and style is done this way:

```
$("div[style='width: 420px; text-align: left;']");
```

And a selector for wildcard ID (in the front) is like this:

```
$("[id^=targ_mt1_]");
```

How do you combine the two?

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets of the wildcard selector come before the square brackets of the style selector:

```
$("textarea[id^=targ_mt1_][style='width: 420px; text-align: left;']")
```

This can be seen in the following:

```js
const text = 'text';
$("textarea[id^=targ_mt1_][style='width: 420px; text-align: left;']").val(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="targ_mt1_1" style='width: 420px; text-align: left;'></textarea>
```